# Building Qt PostgreSql Driver

Tags: qt, build, driver, postgresql

i have been trying to build the Qt Driver for 2 weeks now , without succeed.
I even moven on windows xp 32 Bit to avoid compatibility Problem with the 64 bit (which i faced when trying to link Psql libraries to my C Program).
Using a normal C compiler does function but when i want to have a GUI.
I tried 
qmake -o Makefile "INCLUDEPATH+=D:/Programme/PostgresSQL/9.0/include" "LIBS+=D:/Programme/PostgresPlus/9.0/lib(or /lib/libpq.lib)" psql.pro 
it generates Makefile debug and release
Now when i try : mingw32-make debug or release or even just mingw32-make

```
D:\Qt\2010.05\qt\src\plugins\sqldrivers\psql>mingw32-make
mingw32-make -f Makefile.Debug all
mingw32-make[1]: Entering directory `D:/Qt/2010.05/qt/src/plugins/sqldrivers/psq
l'
g++ -enable-stdcall-fixup -Wl,-enable-auto-import -Wl,-enable-runtime-pseudo-rel
oc -mthreads -Wl -shared -Wl,--out-implib,d:\Qt\2010.05\qt\plugins\sqldrivers\li
bqsqlpsqld4.a -o ..\..\..\..\plugins\sqldrivers\qsqlpsqld4.dll tmp/obj/debug_sha
red/main.o tmp/obj/debug_shared/qsql_psql.o tmp/obj/debug_shared/moc_qsql_psql.o
-L"d:\Qt\2010.05\qt\lib" -L"d:\Qt\2010.05\qt\lib" tmp\obj\debug_shared\qsqlpsq
ld_resource_res.o -lpq -lQtSqld4 -lQtCored4
d:/qt/2010.05/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe:
cannot find -lpq
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
mingw32-make[1]: *** [..\..\..\..\plugins\sqldrivers\qsqlpsqld4.dll] Error 1
mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory `D:/Qt/2010.05/qt/src/plugins/sqldrivers/psql
'
mingw32-make: *** [debug-all] Error 2
```

I really have no idea what this missing -lpq might be.
Thanks for Helping.
Mehdi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using mingw32's gcc to compile qt and trying to use postgreql library compiled with MSVC.

MSVC uses .LIB for libraries while Mingw32 (gcc + binutils) uses .a or .so files for libraries.

You can try either of the following methods:
a. compile Qt using MSVC.
b. use mingw32 to compile postgresql and use its libraries.